# vmdk image without /dev/root

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmdk

I have vmdk server image without /dev/root, I want to deploy it with DigitalOcean (they support custom images). I created images, started droplet, but unable to connect via ssh. I entered RecoveryConsole and got this error:

[image]

It says: `no /dev/root` - well nothing unexpected.

Could you help me how handle this? I need to have an operational server from this image.

Comment: Your image partition has no `/dev` directory.

Comment: yeah, how can I fix it? I can not create another image. Is it possible to launch the server from this image and create /dev directory after (I can ssh server in Recover Mode - would it be enough)? Sorry for stupid question, I will appreciate any help

Comment: No, this is not possible without direct hardware access and cracking the computer. You need to recreate your image.

Comment: sorry, this is nonsense. The dev directory is not missing, the kernel failed to mount the root filesystem, and therefore there is no /dev directory! Obviously, you had the root partition at /dev/rootvg/rootvol , which the kernel didn't find. That is the root cause of the kernel panic... The error message comes from the kernel trying to move the dev filesystem from the initrd mount to the real rootfs, which doesn't exist...

Comment: Thank you @Martin, could you please advise how can I fix this?

Comment: find out why your kernel did not find any volume groups. You mentioned that you moved the vmdk image - maybe the scsi controller emulated by your hypervisor is not supported in your linux... kernel 2.6 is very old! I would start to find out inside the emergency shell if the linux detected any hard disks at all...

Comment: @Martin is right, sorry I was blinded. ^^